# MySQL Delete from database where count of grouped records less than value

Tags: mysql

I have a database similar to this:

```
Name    State
Bill    CA
Joe     NY
Susan   CA
```

I know I can get a total count of the number of records for each state like this:

```
SELECT State, COUNT(*) as count FROM users GROUP BY State
```

I'm trying to delete all records where the total count of states is less than 2 (or any arbitrary number)

Something like this (Pseudocode):

```
 DELETE FROM users WHERE totalUsersInState < 2
```

So the final database should be like this

```
Name    State
Bill    CA
Susan   CA
```

What is the correct syntax for that? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to do a delete with a HAVING clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705996/possible-to-do-a-delete-with-a-having-clause)

Comment: Well less than two is a special case .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a join to an inline view (a *derived table* in the MySQL parlance)

Write it as a SELECT statement first

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM users t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.state
           FROM users r
          GROUP 
             BY r.state
         HAVING SUM(1) < 2
       ) s
    ON s.state = t.state
```

Verify that these are the rows we want to delete, and then convert that into a DELETE statement by just replacing the first SELECT keyword...

```
DELETE t.*
  FROM ...
```

Note that this will not remove a row with a NULL value for `state` because of the equality comparison in the join predicate.

Answer (score 0):

One option, fins all states with fewer than less that 2 users, then delete all records for those states.

```
DELETE FROM
  users
WHERE
  state IN (SELECT state FROM users GROUP BY state HAVING COUNT(*) < 2)
```

Or *(because the `< 2` means "delete users where they are the only user in the state")*...

```
DELETE FROM
  users
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM users lookup
               WHERE lookup.Name <> users.Name
                 AND lookup.State = users.State
             )
             -- WHERE NOT EXISTS (any _other_ user that's in the same state)
             -- => WHERE this is the only user in the state
```

Comment: @PM77-1 That's a false optimisation.  Go search the millions of other questions about that.  It's not a discussion for this question.

Comment: It's simply cleaner.

Comment: @PM77-1 I disagree, and ***It's not a discussion for this question.***

Comment: The first query won't work because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: The second statement will fail for the same reason as the first: Error 1093 You can't specify target table '%s' for update in FROM clause