# MySQL DELETE a SELECT result

Tags: mysql, delphi-xe

I have a SELECT that gives a result set as expected:

```
  SELECT iper.ip, trafikk.port, COUNT(trafikk.port) as Antall FROM trafikk 
    Inner JOIN iper ON iper.id = trafikk.FK_ID 
    Group by IPer.IP 
    having Antall=4 and trafikk.port=445
```

Result example:
http://tore.aasli.net/sql/Delete.jpg

Now, if I want to DELETE these SELECTed rows, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Post code/error messages as text here, instead of linking to pictures hosted on external servers. They might go away and then this question will turn incomplete.

Comment: There are no error messages in my SELECT sql. The question is how to construct a DELETE to delete the result set, preferentially in one SQL (for example based on my SELECT sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to do a delete with a HAVING clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705996/possible-to-do-a-delete-with-a-having-clause)

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM iper 
WHERE iper.ip IN(
    SELECT iper.ip 
    FROM trafikk
    WHERE iper.id = trafikk.FK_ID AND trafikk.port=445
    Group by iper.ip 
    having COUNT(trafikk.port)=4
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this sql gives an error "Uknown column 'trafikk.port' in 'having clause'.  I put a comma between "iper.ip" and "count(Trafikk.port).

Comment: try now, it was my mistake.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have 2 tables. One IPer table, one Trafikk table.  There is a 1:n relation between the IPer table (the one side with IPer.ID) and Trafikk.FK_ID.  So Trafikk may have many rows for each Iper.IP

Comment: Thanks Ernesto.  I think we're closer now.  But still an "error 1241" "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: Don't post code that doesn't work.  What is this???  `...WHERE iper.ip IN(SELECT iper.ip, trafikk.port, COUNT(trafikk.port) as Antall FROM trafikk...`

Comment: the idea is make a selection into an In() operator

Comment: Try again, and please post your tables sql code for testing

Comment: I have also tried "having COUNT(trafikk.port)=4 and trafikk.port=445" but no joy.  Still getting SQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column.  The SELECT itself works OK, but not with the "DELETE From iper WHERE iper.ip IN" in front.  Would posting the tables and rows be any help?

Comment: try removing , (, trafikk.port) on select. but it would be more easy if you post your tables and sample data, just for testing

Comment: I need the Trafikk.Port since the Select must count occurences where Trafikk.Port = 4.  Removing it will cause another error.

Comment: Finally here you haved

Comment: I made my self the tables and tested my code and thas the resulting query

Comment: Sorry for the necessary comments.  It works now, I just did a minor addition to the last line: having COUNT(trafikk.port)=4.  Thanks a bunch!  :-)

Comment: Please @Tore if this answer was useful for you give me a up vote