# How to skip rows with same column values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a table as below:

```````
ColA    ColB    ColC
`````  ``````  ``````  
1       Steve   Rodgers  
2       Tony    Stark  
3       Steve   Jobs
```````

Resultant table should look like this:

```````
ColA    ColB    ColC
`````  ``````  ``````   
2       Tony    Stark
```````

Rows with same value in `ColB` should be removed. How can I delete/exclude such rows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705996/possible-to-do-a-delete-with-a-having-clause

Answer (score 2):

You can use a similar logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLB NOT IN (SELECT COLB 
                   FROM TABLE 
                   GROUP BY COLB 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: It's possible to use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` without a `COUNT(*)` in the select?

Comment: @Zorkolot yes it is

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where colb = t.colb and cola <> t.cola
)
```

Comment: what if ColA is identical and ColC is different?

Comment: The OP's sample data does not imply that there are duplicates in colA. In fact the exact opposite.

Comment: He didn't mentioned that ColA is an identity, i think the where clause must be `where colb = t.colb and (cola <> t.cola OR colc <> t.colc)`

Comment: If there is a case of cola not being unique, then `where colb = t.colb and (cola <> t.cola OR colc <> t.colc)` won't work either. For 2 different rows with values `2 Tony Stark` the result will contain both these rows.

Comment: You are right, then it also requires a `DISTINCT` keyword in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to note that you can do this with aggregation:

```
select min(cola) as col1, colb, min(colc) as colc
from t
group by colb
having count(*) = 1;
```

If the count is `1`, then the `min()` brings back the values in that row.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a covering index with leading column `ColB` you could also use `LAG`/`LEAD`. This can scan the index in order (without needing a sort) and retain rows where `ColB` is not the same as either of its neighbours

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                LAG(ColB) OVER (ORDER BY ColB) AS PrevColB,
                LEAD(ColB) OVER (ORDER BY ColB) AS NextColB
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  IIF(ColB IN ( PrevColB, NextColB ), 0, 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Col1 INT,
  Col2 VARCHAR(45),
  Col3 VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'Steve',  'Rodgers'),  
(2, 'Tony',  'Stark' ), 
(3, 'Steve',  'Jobs');

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(Col2) 
           FROM T TT 
           WHERE T.Col2 = TT.Col2 
          );
```

**Returns:**

```
+------+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3  |
+------+------+-------+
|    2 | Tony | Stark |
+------+------+-------+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0629443682c4de81dad78f9ee89dbdbb)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY …)` to count the similar values in a column and then filter by that count, e.g.:

```
-- Set up the test data
CREATE TABLE [person] (
   [personId]   Integer
  ,[givenName]  NVarChar(100)
  ,[familyName] NVarChar(100)
);
INSERT INTO [person] VALUES
     (1,    N'Steve',   N'Rodgers')
    ,(2,    N'Tony',    N'Stark' )
    ,(3,    N'Steve',   N'Jobs')
;
-- /Set up the test data


-- Use a common table expression to derive our count
WITH tData AS (
    SELECT
             *
            ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [P].[givenName]) AS [givenNameInstances]
        FROM [person] AS [P]
)
SELECT
         [tD].[personId]
        ,[tD].[givenName]
        ,[tD].[familyName]
    FROM tData AS [tD]
    WHERE [tD].[givenNameInstances] = 1 -- Only return results where the count was 1
;

DROP TABLE [person];
```